# Dynamic content for product price

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I've written an AMPscript for showing up to 4 items in an abandoned cart email.

The script works fine but I still have an issue.

The text email should show the standard price AND the special price only when there's a special one.

Now in the HTML, I have the placeholder for a standard price and a special price. I wonder if there's a way for showing the Special price placeholder only when the special price field is populated.

Is there any documentation on this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using if/else conditional statement. In below, you will have to add a source from which those prices are pulled from:

```
%%[ 
var @standardPrice, @specialPrice

set @standardPrice = ...
set @specialPrice = ...

if (not empty(@specialPrice) and not empty(@standardPrice)) then]%%

standardPrice: %%=v(@standardPrice)=%%
<br>
specialPrice: %%=v(@specialPrice)=%%

%%[elseif not empty(@specialPrice) then ]%%

standardPrice: %%=v(@standardPrice)=%%

%%[endif]%%
```